# Modify content of div with id using AJAX based on PHP output

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am working on a website for a restaurant and each category is represented by a "card". Each card is an image paired with the title of the Category. Now, there are two types of cards:

1.Once pressed it enters inside an if in a PHP file and shows other cards(Example: Drinks(Pressed) => Alcholic and Non-Alcholic Cards show up.

2.Once pressed it enters inside the else in a PHP file and shows the Menu for that specific Category.(Example: Wines(Pressed) => A menu with all the wines shows up.

To handle everything, I made this HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cards" id="cards">
        <?php
            require 'logic.php';
            echo getAllCards();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./SCRIPTS/cardReload.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, there are two main DIVs, cards and menu. Inside the cards div I will hold the different cards and inside the menu div I will hold the menu. Here's the logic.php file(simplified):

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
  $pressedCardName = $_POST['name'];
  echo getAllCards($pressedCardName);
}

function getAllCards($cardName="")
{
  if(condition)//show other cards
  {
    return printCard($cardName,1);
  }
  else //show the menu
  {
    return printCard($cardName,2);
  }

}

function printCard($name, $option)//The option argument is not necessary right now
{
  $str="";
    $str.="
    <div class=\"card\">
    <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick="thisIsJSfunction(this)" name=\"".$name."\">
        <img src=\"./STRUCTURE/IMAGES/".$name.".jpg\" class=\"card_image\">
        <div class=\"animated-button\">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <p>".$name."</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    ";
  return $str;
}
```

Now, in order for the card to interface with PHP and bring the new content I handle it in the cardReload.js file using AJAX:

```
function thisIsJSfunction(e){
    // ajax
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "logic.php",
    data: {name: e['name']},
    success: function(res){
    $('#cards').html(res);
        .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
          console.log( textStatus );
        })
        .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
          $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
      });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log("Status: " + textStatus+"\n"+"Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
```

A lot of the code above is not necessary but I pasted it so the context can be clear, I want to point out the line `$('#cards').html(res);` in the cardReload.js file. As you can see, by default, it overwrites the content inside the div with the id=cards. This works fine for the 1st type of cards but for the second type of cards that need to modify the content of the div with the id=menu it doesn't work at all. The problem comes down to this: How can I tell the ajax script from the PHP file( the if and else ) to modify the content of the #cards div or the #menu div, not only the #cards div.

I want to make this clear, the source code is much longer for me so in case you find anything that should not work, is because I cut a lot of things and only let the essential code, but everything works, this is for sure. I know that my question can be confusing but I have been working on this for a while now and any amount of help in the right direction would be very helpful. In case you need more explaination or details, I can easily modify the post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I know that my question can be confusing"_ - Yes, it is. I've read it twice and am not even sure what you're asking about. We don't need that much background or any code that's not relevant. I would recommend rewriting the question to include a detailed explanation of your issue/problem, example data, expected output and what you're currently getting. You should also show what debugging you've done (to narrow the issue down). Errors in the console? Read through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the feedback, I was expecting it to be confusing but I tried my best to minimize it. Just so I don't have to rewrite it again, is it possible to dynamically change the id of the div that is going to be overwrited using PHP?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by _"change the id of the div that is going to be overwrited using PHP"_. Are you talking about changing the id of a div you've populated/going to populate with contents that comes from an ajax request? You need to explain the flow properly. But if you ask me, if you need to dynamically change id's, you should probably rethink your current solution. But yes, it's possible to dynamically change the id's of divs.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I think I understand why I'm not clear. I'm talking about chaning the id of this line ```$('#cards').html(res);``` thas is inside the cardReload.js file. ```$('#THIS_ID_COMES_FROM_PHP').html(res);```. So I would need to tell the javascript file to change the id of the AJAX script.

Comment: Pass it as a second parameter to your `onclick` handler?

Comment: @El_Vanja Compliments! I can't understand why I haven't thought about that, you saved me a LOT of time. Thank You!

Comment: That's just a classic example of not seeing the forest for the trees. And you're welcome.